# length vs head vs last in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, declarative

I know 2 of these statements are true, but I dont know which

Let `e` be an expression of type `[Int]`

1. there exists `e` such that: Evaluation of `head e` won't finish but `last e` will
2. there exists `e` such that: Evaluation of `last e` won't finish but `head e` will
3. there exists `e` such that: Evaluation of `length e` won't finish but `last e` will

Seems clear to me that 2 is true, but I can't see how 1 or 3 can be true.

My thinking is that in order to calculate the length of a list you need to get to the last one, making 1 and 3 impossible

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: What is the type of `myList = [last [1..], 2]`, assuming numeric literals are of type `Int`?

Comment: that would be [Int] but i cant see your point

Comment: And no, its not homework, its just a test question(i have the answer) i dont understand

Comment: @pepe22 hint: try your three statements on @chi 's `myList` :-) Do it in your head or pen/paper first.

Comment: Your question is really ambiguous. The only reading that seems to make any sense is "Choose all of the following sets of conditions for which an `e :: [Int]` exists that satisfies the condition". Can you clarify it? And maybe with Chi's comment you can answer it yourself now?

Comment: @chi and drRobertz thanks, it was a great example, couldnt see it at first ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a test question, I won't answer it directly, but instead, here are some hints; it'd be better if you work this out yourself.

Since we're talking about computations that don't terminate, it might be useful to define one such computation. However, if this confuses you you can safely ignore this and refer only to examples that don't include this.

```
-- `never` never terminates when evaluated, and can be any type.
never :: a
never = never
```

---

### Question 1

Consider the list `[never, 1]`, or alternatively the list `[last [1..], 1]` as suggested by @chi.

---

### Question 2

Consider the list `[1..]`, or alternatively the list `[1, never]`.

---

### Question 3

Consider the definition of `length`:

```
length [] = 0
length (_:xs) = 1 + length xs
```

Under what conditions does `length` not terminate? How does this relate to `last`?

Comment: @drRobertz I disagree, since 1) and 2) are contradictory, and 2) and 3) are contradictory. [Spoiler, text in URL.](http://and_3_is_clearly_false.) I don't see how you've proven 1) and 3)? For the example that chi gave, `length [last [1..], 1] = 2`, at least in GHC v8.4.3. Furthermore, it is stated that "I know 2 of these statements are true, but I dont know which"

Comment: great answer and thanks for not just giving away the answer! also i think that chi's list is a better example for beginners since everyone will understand last of an infinity list but your definition of never is a bit "advanced". Please consider editing it to show chi's list first :)

Comment: @AJFarmar You're right, I was too quick. But then the question should be rephrased to remove the ambiguity. As it stands it says for an expression `e`, two of the statements are true, which they cannot be. It should be something like, for each statement, there exists a statement `e`...